# C++ char spacing in console output, UTF-16 characters

Tags: c++, console, utf-16

I'm making a game in C++ console using UTF-16 characters to make it little bit more interesting, but some characters are different size then others. So, when I print the level, things after character are moved further than others. Is there any way how to add spacing between characters with some console function, I try to google something helpful, but I have not found nothing.
[image: decripted problem on image]

I tried to change font size by CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX, but it changed nothing, maybe i implement it in the wrong way, or it not work with UTF-16 characters.

```
// i tried this

CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
cfi.dwFontSize.X= 24;
cfi.dwFontSize.Y= 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I expect that this will heavily depend on the particular console you're using.  Some less Unicode-friendly consoles will treat all characters as the same size (possibly cutting off the right half of larger characters), and some consoles will cause larger characters to push the rest of the line to the right (which is what I see in the linked image).  The most reasonable consoles I've observed have a set of characters considered "double-wide" and reserve two monospace columns for those characters instead of one, so the rest of the line still fits into the grid.

That said, you may want to experiment with different console programs.  Can I assume you are on Windows?  In that case, you might want to give [Windows Terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701?hl=en-us&gl=us) a try.  If that doesn't work, there are other console programs available, such as msys's [Mintty](https://mintty.github.io/), or [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/).

Comment: So if i udrestand it correctly, this character takes two places of one normal character, in my code after every character i print space to make look more like square, so if i just delete space in case of this one character, it would solve my issue? Also yes im using windows, and im using clion console.

Comment: That would be the ideal solution, but it only works if the console guarantees that all characters are a whole number of columns wide.  In the image you linked, it looks like some of the characters are more than 1 but less than 2 columns wide, so you might not be able to solve the problem by just changing the number of spaces (which are always 1 column wide).

Comment: I tried it and its now too short, this character is more like 1.5 width of normal sized character :(, i will try other consols then, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

So, after some intense googling i found the solution. And solution is fight fire with fire. Unicode include character Thin Space, that is 1/5 of the normal space, so if i include two of them with one normal space after my problematic character, the output is diplaying how i want. If anybody runs into some simliar issue, unicode have lot of different sized spaces. I found [Website](https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html) that shows them all of them, with their propperties.

[fixed output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYob6.png)